# Disable Graphql Introspection on .NET

Tags: .net, graphql, introspection

I am trying to disable GraphQL Introspection in my project and not having much luck with specific framework I am using.
Im using the graphql-dotnet library v3
Should i update to the lastest?(v7)

I tried creating a custom schema filter and returning false. I take the idea from this issue https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/2692

Answer (score 0):

Debugging i realized that the query object that comes with the request give me the information of what Operation its running. So calling query.OperationName tells you if its Introspection, mutation or a simple query.

This implementation solved my problem:

```
if(query.OperationName == "IntrospectionQuery")
            {
                return StatusCode(500, new { Message = "You can't execute introspection queries." });
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).